# Object Promise returned and output rather than value

Tags: javascript, tesseract, tesseract.js

I have been looking through promise questions for the last hour and am totally clueless so I decided to write a question as I am unable to store the value of the function in a variable without it resulting in a promise.

```
const T = require("tesseract.js");

async function imageCheck(T, url){
    T.recognize(url, 'eng')
    .then(out => {return(out.data.text)});
}
url = imageCheck(T, 'EXAMPLEURL');
Promise.resolve(url)
console.log("the url is "+url)
```

My output is:

```
the url is [object Promise]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Promise.resolve()` will return another `Promise`. You should use `then` to get value.

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

I would recommend the following ways.

```js
const T = require("tesseract.js");

async function imageCheck(T, url){
    const out = await T.recognize(url, 'eng');
    return out.data.text;
}

imageCheck(T, 'EXAMPLEURL')
  .then( url => console.log("the url is "+url));
```

**OR**

```js
const T = require("tesseract.js");

async function imageCheck(T, url){
    return T.recognize(url, 'eng');
}

imageCheck(T, 'EXAMPLEURL')
   .then(out => console.log("the url is "+out.data.text));
```